# What is the reason for the name `weak_ptr::lock()`?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, terminology, naming, weak-ptr

Many of our developers don't understand what creating a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` has to do with locking things.  By them, the term 'lock' is associated with mutexes first.

It could have been called `use` or `safeguard` or `lease` or `promote` for instance...  but hey, it isn't, and it's our responsibility to learn the standard.

But to them, this is so bad an issue that another class that copied this idiom had to be renamed, causing numerous lines of code to follow the rename.  Now we have sacrificed consistency with the standard for just a little intuitivity.

Does anyone know how the choice for the name `lock()` was made?

Comment: It's really hard to come up with a term that is both usefully generic *and* usefully specific. The word "use" provides no information at all. You might as well call it "do_something".

Comment: I'm not at all convinced this question is on-topic for SO.  One of the reasons for closure is "primarily opinion based" - which this is.  It is also a question about "why did people make this choice when boost::weak_ptr was first developed?"  Since then the answer has been "backwards compatability".

Comment: @Martin - Agree that it is not a perfect question, but there are people around here that might have "been there" and actually know the answer first hand.

Comment: @MartinBonner the situation I'm in is that I can't explain to fellow developers why they _should_ understand the meaning of this function by it's name.  I'll try rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It locks the shared object in memory, and prevents it being deleted.

It has nothing to do with locking a mutex or anything like that.

Comment: Then words like 'safeguard', 'pin', or even 'lock_in' would be more intuitive, wouldn't they?

Comment: Perhaps.  You should have been part of the boost review about fifteen years ago to change that though (or at the very latest, contributed to the development of TR1 ?12? years ago).  It's all much too late now.

Comment: @xtofl prior to the call to `lock()` the existence of the pointee object is unknown. After the call to lock, it's known (and fixed). It either exists or it doesn't. I suppose an alternate name could be `open_shroedingers_cat_box()` :-)

Comment: Of all the names you have suggested, I think "pin" captures the meaning best - but I think you are very foolish not to have just learnt the standard and used it.